# How would the Dragonborn transformation affect Grafts, Deformities, and other non-racial physical traits?

Tags: dnd-3.5e

The Dragonborn rebirth process seems to allude that such things would be removed or cured somehow, or would they be incorporated into the new Dragonborn form in such a way that they would be part of the new form?

Things that I can think of that would fall under this include Willing Deformity, Grafts, and Draconic Feats...  I think there are more but I can't remember off the top of my head.  Basically any physical aspects acquired beyond your normal race.  I guess this could include some templates too.

If many of these would be overridden, how would you compensate the player for giving up things they spent feats, gold, and perhaps even levels on?

Comment: Drift effects might also be affected.

Answer (score 3):

### By RAW, they aren't overridden

The Dragonborn is not taking on an entirely new body.  Some aspects of the original form remain, as per the description.  It specifies that only racial characteristics are removed.  So things like grafts, willing deformity (on a Good aligned character?  What?) will remain.  They are not racial characteristics.

Here's what you keep from the Race entry and any Template entries for your character pre-dragonborn-transformation;

- Type and Subtypes (You retain your original and gain the dragonblood
  subtype)
- Racial Hit Dice (You retain these and their benefits - BAB, base saves, hp)
- Ability Modifiers (stack with Dragonborn modifiers)
- Size
- Speed (along with any special movement methods and related abilities (Dwarf's speed in heavy armor, for example))
- Languages (plus Draconic as an automatic language)
- Favored Class (Also gain Fighter as a favored class and may multiclass to Paladin freely)
- any LA (i.e. even if all or most of the benefits of a template or race are removed, you still retain the LA).

Comment: Willing Deformity is restricted to Any Evil, but isn't removed if your alignment changes.  Dragonborn is Any NonEvil, so... If say you reform even a little bit, it's possible.

EDIT: Also, deformities can occur without Willing Deformity.  That's just the most common means of getting them.